# How to get Exchange Named Properties using Python?

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Is there a way to get Exchange Named Properties of a mailbox using Python?

Comment: Have you tried [exchangelib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/exchangelib/1.9.3)?

Comment: @Raf Yes I've tried exchangelib. There is a constraint in it, where you have to register the values of a mail as shown below:
    # If folder items have extended properties, you need to register them 
    before you can access them. Create
    a subclass of ExtendedProperty and set your custom property_id:
    class LunchMenu(ExtendedProperty):
    property_set_id = '12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234'
    property_name = 'Catering from the cafeteria'
    property_type = 'String' 

But I want to get these parameters from any given mail in the server.